# Export file in csv to TXT with 2 Row

Tags: excel, vba, csv, export-csv

I need help for a csv file to export it to txt, It presents 2 columns "A" and "B", what I need is to create 1 txt file for each A1 and B1, and so on, but with the condition that A1 is above B1, that is; In A1 I have the "Title" and in B1 "I have the content" I have seen that there are macros but I have not been able to do it.

Take this code as an example the another user, but it creates the name of the document with character error and does not add the title "A1" in the content:

```
Sub DataDump()

    Dim X
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim StrFolder As String

    StrFolder = "C:\temp"
    X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X)
    Open StrFolder & "\" & X(lngRow, 1) & ".txt" For Output As #1
    Write #1, X(lngRow, 2)
    Close #1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where is the problem, exactly? It would be helpful to see the code you have

Comment: They are not useful, what happens is that they are for a single column, and I do not understand the subject very well ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Can you please add example data and also an example for the output you want to have? Your question is unclear. What do you mean by *"1 txt file for each A1 and B1"* There is only one cell A1 and one cell B1 in a sheet, so what do you mean by each? Please clarify.